# xaml databinding and navigating

Tags: c#, wpf

I am working on a small rss reader written in wpf (I am just learning wpf).
I found [this tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WpfXml2WayDataBinding.aspx) on codeproject.

What I would like to know is how do I navigate using buttons (forward and backward) 
without binding it to a listbox like in The example ? ...
Assuming that the listbox doesn't exists.

So how would the DataTemplate looks like? Or what to change in the code?
Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: Why not use a Page if you want to navigate?

Comment: hi ...could you please provide an example ? Iam ont sure how this could be done, but i just want to NAVIGATE to the next item and backward just like the movenext() moveback() ...

Comment: Oh I see, I think Bas B has a better suggestion

Answer (score 0):

You should implement  a custom [Selector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.aspx) in WPF that will select the next and previous items based on button clicks. The control will contain Back/Forward buttons. This might be out of the scope if you are just learning WPF though.

Comment: i will check it, i just had no idea where to start..i already done a progect in c# but iam moving to wpf ...just to start learning it (learning by doing )

Thanks anyway for your reply ..:)  
(an example would be great if you have any)

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't already, I'd highly recommend looking into the MVVM design pattern.

With it, your ViewModel would contain

- `ObservableCollection<SomeModel> SomeModelList`
- `SomeModel CurrentModel`
- `ICommand ForwardCommand`
- `ICommand BackCommand`

Your data area would have it's `DataContext` property bound to `{Binding CurrentModel}`, while your Buttons would have their `Command` properites bound to `{Binding ForwardCommand}` and `{Binding BackCommand}`, which would simply move the Current item forward or back by one space.

If you're interested, I wrote a brief introduction to MVVM [here](http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/05/08/simplemvvmexample/)

Comment: Thank you, iam definetly reading your brief introduction..thanks again